# Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression

Tags: android, insert, expression, assignment-operator

At the line 38 "data[i];" I get the following error "Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression" can anybody help solve this.

Thanks

```
package org.physionet.challenge2011;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.Log;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;



public class ChallengeEntry {

public static final String DEBUGTAG = ChallengeEntry.class.toString();
final static int FS= 500;                   //Sampling Frequency
final static int CH= 12;
final static int MAX_RT= 220;               //Max expected beats in minutes
final static int WIN=FS*10;
final static double PKS_MIN=40/6;               // Minimum number of expected peaks in 10s    
final static int FRGT=(int) (FS*0.04);          // Window for ignoring consecutive peaks 
final static short [] W={1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1}; // Weights for each channel
final static double PK_TH=500;      // Peak value hardcoded based on sample data
static short [] sum = new short[WIN]; //Array for storing summed channel data

//Define Quality values (could also be defined as enum...)
final static int INIT=0;
final static int GOOD = 0;
final static int BAD =  1;
short[] data=new short[WIN*CH];

synchronized public int get_result(InputStream iFile, final ECG_MetaData m_MetaData) throws IOException {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(iFile);
    //try {
        data = (short[])in.readObject();
    int i;
    data[i];
    i=8+(4*CH);
int n = 0;  
short []    y= new short[WIN];
    for(n = 0; n<(CH*WIN); n+=CH);

    y[n] = data[n];

    n++;

    canvas.drawPath path;
        path.moveTo(0, y[0]);

        for (int x=1; x<(WIN); x++);
            path.lineTo(x, y[x]);
            Paint paint;
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Canvas.drawpath(path, paint);
```

Comment: if you want to use data[i] then do like short x=data[i]

Answer (score 0):

What does this line do:

```
data[i];
```

Also the line above makes it invalid!

```
int i;
```

Comment: the line data[i]; was meant to allow me to use the data stored in the short memory, have I done that wrong?.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, new to java, but I think I have created new short memory called "data" in an array and then loaded the file and am trying to read the individual bits of data from the binary code in the order I need them. Therefore I have called the individual code that I need "i" I think.

Comment: Oh and yes the "int i;" I have now removed, only added it as eclipse suggested it to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

int i; is fine, although there's no point to it, data[i]; is throwing an error because you're not declaring anything, or assigning any values or really *doing* anything with that line, it's. Either way it's probably just lint that's complaining about it anyway. I turn Lint checking off till I export cause it always seems to throw fits about nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line: data[i], the element of short array is initialised as 0 by default.